# Finding the minimum root of the function while there is an interval for it

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have some functions like the below one:

```
(1/2)(-1+(3 + Abs[3 - 4 p] + Abs[3 - 2 p])/(Abs[3 + 2p]))
```

and I need to find the minimum value of p for which f(p)=0. When I use "Solve" command:

```
Solve[f==0,-p]
```

I get no answer. In fact there is an interval for p in which f(p)=0, but I need the minimum value of p on in other words I need to find the first place in which f(p)=0.

Comment: For such functions making use of Abs, where have whole ranges that are zero (as can be seen by `Plot[f, {p, -1, 4}]`), you will have better luck using FindRoot (`FindRoot[f, {p, 1.}]`)

Comment: $\LaTeX$ is supported on this site, but with the use of \$ or $$. For code, you can use the backticks or a four-space indentation.

Comment: Dear  Manuel --Moe-- G , Thank you so much for your helpful guidance.

Comment: Dear  corey979, Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: Plotting the function will help you decide and when one can either change `Abs[x]` to `x` or `-x`:  `Plot[f, {p, -0, 2}]`.  And then use `Solve`.

Comment: Dear  Jim Baldwin, Thank you so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 5):

Reduce can be useful for this kind of thing:

```
f[p_] := (1/2) (-1 + (3 + Abs[3 - 4 p] + Abs[3 - 2 p])/(Abs[3 + 2 p]));
Reduce[f[p] == 0, p, Reals]

3/4 <= p <= 3/2
```

Hence the smallest is 3/4.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize.html)

```
f[p_] = (1/2) (-1 + (3 + Abs[3 - 4 p] + Abs[3 - 2 p])/(Abs[3 + 2 p]));

Minimize[{p, f[p] == 0}, p]

(*  {3/4, {p -> 3/4}}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help.